# How to set roles or policy in asp.net MVC 6 windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.Net MVC 6 Application with windows authentication
how do I create roles or policies in and where to set them.

I know that we set

```
        [Authorize(Roles ="editor")]
```

but I don't know how to add users to this editor role or groups
also where do I create these roles.
how these roles work, how the system authenticate, where the system authenticate

Answer (score 0):

You'd set them in your Active Directory. Roles in Windows Authentication map to group membership.

However role checks for Windows auth are broken in RC1. This is fixed in RC2.